# PHP, Javascript - Outputting date to 'each' grid independantly

Tags: javascript, php, html, foreach, element

Basically, I want to input the date into 'item5' when I click on the image in item6 with every new `flavour` independently. (as well it switching the image, as I have it). The way I have it set at the moment, it does do - but it only occurs in the first instance of the class. I would like it to enter into each new container, the way that I have with the src-change function (this method of not using IDs is new to me). However, I cannot figure how to forward the date into the item5 of every new instance. Do I need to rejig my code, or am I missing something simple here?

```
<?php
  $FLAVOUR = $_GET['flavour'];

  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM node WHERE node.flavour = :flavour");
  $stmt->bindValue(':flavour',$FLAVOUR);
  $stmt->execute();

  $flavours = $stmt->fetchALL();
  echo "<div class='grid-container'>";
  echo "<div class='item1'>Header</div>";
  echo "</div>";

  if($flavours){
    foreach ($flavours as $flavour) {
      echo "<div class='grid-container'>";
      echo "<div class='item2'><img src='{$flavour['image']}'></div>";
      echo "<div class='item3'>{$flavour['flavour']}</div>";
      echo "<div class='item4'>{$flavour['area']}, <button class='btn' data-clipboard-text='{$flavour['link']}'>{$flavour['waypoint']}</button></div>";
      echo "<div class='item5'><p id='p1'></p></div>";
      echo "<div class='item6'><img src='https://i.imgur.com/yymBeSS.jpg' onclick='checkAtreyu(this)'  /></div>";
      echo "</div>";
    }
    echo "";
  }
else
{
  echo "<p>Can't find any destination records.</p>";
}
?>
```

javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function checkAtreyu(element) {

        if (element.src == "https://i.imgur.com/yymBeSS.jpg") 
        {
            element.src = "https://i.imgur.com/ZlTnzBL.jpg";
            document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = Date();
            //element.innerHTML = Date();
        }
        else 
        {
            element.src = "https://i.imgur.com/yymBeSS.jpg";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Is the date not one of the queried fields? If not, what is the relevance of `Date` from the javascript? It'll be a similar issue like before, that you can only have one element with `id='p1'` within the document.

Comment: The Date in my JS is my current attempt at outputting the date upon clicking the image. Which works, but exactly as you say, does not work they way I want it because I can only have one `id=p1` per document. I then tried things simular to how you helped with the image switch... but to no avail. It feels more troublesome since I want the onclick of item6 to now also output a date to item5. Previously we were able to just change "(this)". The reason to have the date would just be an indicator of when in time I clicked the image, so I can look back on it throughout the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to other elements based on the current element, assuming the element structure remains consistent.

Try the example below. (no element id used for this handling)

```js
function checkAtreyu(element) {

    if (element.src == "https://i.imgur.com/yymBeSS.jpg") 
    {
        element.src = "https://i.imgur.com/ZlTnzBL.jpg";

      // <img>   item6 <div>      item5 <div>         <p> tag
        element.parentElement.previousElementSibling.firstChild.innerHTML = Date();

        //document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = Date();
        //element.innerHTML = Date();
    }
    else 
    {
        element.src = "https://i.imgur.com/yymBeSS.jpg";
    }
}
```

```html
<div class='item5'><p></p></div>
<div class='item6'><img src='https://i.imgur.com/yymBeSS.jpg' onclick='checkAtreyu(this)'  /></div>
<hr>
<div class='item5'><p></p></div>
<div class='item6'><img src='https://i.imgur.com/yymBeSS.jpg' onclick='checkAtreyu(this)'  /></div>
```

Comment: An absoloute glory! Thank you so much, Paul.
Although there is a LOT of information on coding out there, it is difficult to find the precise information that you need to know sometimes. You have tought me alot today, I was not aware you could do so much navigation with parent/sibling/child. Answered my perfectly and gave me new tools to work with for future too. Wish I could upvote you more!